# Sharing redux store between more than 1 Navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I need to share the same store between more than one navigator (Nested navigation) to be able to access the data from the two navigators.

I have made a work-around to solve this issue but, I need to know what is the right solution for this issue.

I have exported the store from one file like this:

```
export const store = createStore(marketOrderReducer);
```

Then, I imported it and used it in the other file and it worked:

```
import { store } from "../screens/marketNavigation";

export default function cartNavigation() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
 <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} independent={true}>
    .
    .
    .
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
```

Comment: Actually Redux should cover the WHOLE APP, therefore you should not have more than one store in the redux part. However, if you need more than one store, you can use MobX or even better MobX State Tree. You can achieve your logic with these very easily

Comment: So, you mean that my solution is the right solution?

Comment: No, please read again. Redux should cover the app, it should not has more than one store. Of course you can customize it for your own need but there is already a great library for that: MobX

Comment: So, I can use one public variable, say public.store as my store and use it all around the app. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: My suggestion is that you should research about Redux and MobX